# Hibernate One Entity Multiple Tables per Country

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, web

I'm developing a web app, that becouse of legal issues, I have to divide the tables per country.
I can divide by schema such as schema_name will contain data config tables, schema_name_ar will contain AR data, schema_name_ES will contain ES data, etc. 
I could also developed to have to name the tables like TABLE_A_ES, TABLE_A_AR, TABLE_A_ZA, etc. 
For now there will be no difference in table columns so I want to reuse the entity.

Depending on the user who logs in he will be able to CRUD on specific tables.
Can Hibernate/JPA do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature in 'pure' JPA.

However, I guess you could implement your requirement using multi-tenancy features provided by some of the persistence providers (EclipseLink: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant, Hibernate: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html).

Basically, you could use the table-per-tenant approach and treat each country as a separate tenant. You would also need to keep your user entity shared across tenants, and store the tenant identifier alongside other user data.